# nodejs - Parameters I am sending via POST are undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax, express

server.js:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();
    loggedIn = {};

    app.use('/',express.static('www')); // static files
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.listen(8080, function () {
      console.log('Port 8080!');
    });

    app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
        if (typeof req.query.user != 'undefined') {
            user = req.query.user;
            res.status(200).send('Works');
        }
    });

    app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
            user = req.body.user;
            if (typeof users[user] != 'undefined') {
                return res.status(405).send('Access Forbidden');
            } else {
                   loggedIn.push(user);
                   res.status(201).send('New User');
            }
        }
    });
```

client.js requests:

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/user",
        data: {"user" : user},
        dataType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            // success
        },
        error: function() {
            // error case
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/user",
        data: {"user" : user},
        dataType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            // success
        },
        error: function() {
            // error case
        }
    });
```

Even though the GET request works exactly as expected but POST doesn't. Whenever I try to pass a POST request through, it hangs in limbo, even though all the parameters show up in Firebug. When I try to force ContentType to application/json, I get an "Unexpected token u" error an 400 Bad Request, meaning what I am sending through is undefined, even though there are clearly parameters with values visible in Firebug when I check the POST request there and I know for a fact I am passing something given the fact that in Firebug, the variables I am passing have values as seen in the DOM section and those same values pop up in the POST request under Firebug (parameters - user = "some text here").

Comment: have you tried changing `data: {"user" : user}` to `data: JSON.stringify({"user" : user})`?

Comment: what are you getting in `req.body`?

Comment: Have you tried to console.log whole request object? Also, may be you have some protection for POST requests, like CSRF token?

Comment: When you do console.log(req.body), what is the result?

Comment: what is user? a string?

Comment: @Merijndk Yes, it is a string

Comment: @abdulbarik My console prints "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send your data in string

```
 $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/user",
        data: JSON.stringify({"user" : user}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(data) {
            // success
        },
        error: function() {
            // error case
        }
    });
```

Hope it works!

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

when you use Content-Type = application/json
Then all the body will parse into JSON and you not need to parse it
`if(typeof req.body == "string"){
   var body = JSON.parse(req.body)
}`